# Angular directive ng-repeat and scope problemm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some troubles. In directive `commentsFeedback` in `ng-repeat` I'm showing some user comments.
In form after click in response i get new object from server . I'm updating `$scope.users[0].atrb` to response.result but `ng-repeat` in directive don't rewrite this updates.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Myfactory',
    function ($scope, $http, Myfactory){
    $scope.commentFunk = function(comment, commentForm){
        $http.post('url/', {text: comment.text})
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.users[0].atrb = response.result;
            })
            .error(  function (response) {
                console.log('Response', response);
            })
    }
}]);
myApp.directive('commentsFeedback', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: "<h2>Comments</h2>" +
        "<div ng-repeat='key in some_list'>" +
        "<div ng-repeat='item in key.comments_list'><h4>{$ key.name $}</h4> <b>{$ item.author $}:</b> {$ item.text $}" +
        "</div></div>",
        link:function (scope, element, attrs){
            scope.some_list = scope.users[0].atrb;
        }
      }
   });
```

How to re shown elements in directive after getting response from server or how to update elements in directive after `scope.users[0].atrb` have been changed?

Comment: Heh, it's my decision. 
I inserted to controller `$watch` and delete from directive `link:function()`
`$scope.$watch(
        function(oldVal, newVal) {
            updateCommentsList();
        });
    function updateCommentsList(){
        $scope.somelist = $scope.users[0].atrb
    }`

Does any variants to do it more effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just to don't reassign `scope.users[0].atrb` to `scope.some_list` and use it directly in `ng-repeat`. Like so: `<div ng-repeat='key in users[0].atrb'>`. Or may be you just can assign `response.result` to both `users[0].atrb` and `some_list` (I'm just not sure what behind the piece of code you presented here)? Otherwise I suppose you'll have to use `$watch` as you described in your comment.